# What kind of quadrilateral is determined by four sides and a diagonal?

Tags: geometry

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Other_metric_relations) says that

> The shape of a simple quadrilateral is fully determined by the lengths of its sides and one diagonal.

but I have my doubts. For example, the two quadrilaterals in this picture both have the same side lengths and the same yellow diagonal, but are not the same.

[image: two simple quadrilaterals]

Am I missing something here, or are simple quadrilaterals not actually determined (all sides and angles) by the lengths of four sides and a diagonal? If not, what about a convex quadrilateral? Would that be fully determined by those lengths?

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is not *either* of the diagonals, but (at least) one of them.

Comment: If by "lengths" of the sides one means the lengths in say counterclockwise order, then the lengths of the sides together with the length of a diagonal to specified vertices does determine the quadrilateral if it is **convex.** Your example shows the result is not true if we drop convexity.  The Wikipedia article specifies **simple** here, and "simple" does not imply convex. So, a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wikipedia article specifies that the polygon is convex in almost every paragraph of this article.

It is only true for a convex polygon, you just proved that wikipedia can be wrong :).

For a convex polygon i can think of the following proof :

With 4 lengths and 1 diagonal you define 2 unique triangles (a triangle is uniquely defined by the length of his 3 sides) with one common side, and therefore one unique polygon.

Comment: It does specify a convex polygon in almost every paragraph, except the one I quoted from. Hence the confusion. (You wouldn't happen to know of a proof, would you?)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I added a very quick proof for a convex polygon, and your question prove that it's not true for not convex simple polygons.

Comment: I fixed the wikipedia article. If we want to be pedantic, we perhaps add that the order of the side lengths matters, as well as *which* diagonal is given.